# Obter dinâmicamente property "jboss.server.data.dir" do jboss

Tags: java, junit, jboss

Estou tentando realizar testes com jUnit com a finalidade de testar se um diretório pode ser criado no filesystem, para conseguir testar em todos os ambientes preciso obter o caminho do jboss 5.1 dinâmicamente via 
System.getProperty("jboss.server.data.dir"). Ao realizar o teste este parâmetro volta nulo, setando manualmente a property funciona ok mas não conseguiria testar automaticamente nos diversos ambientes.

Tentei usar o "System Rules" para obter esta property, porém sem sucesso também retorna nulo.

```
public final ProvideSystemProperty properties = ProvideSystemProperty.fromResource("jboss.server.data.dir");
```

Como faço para obter no jUnit a propriedade "jboss.server.data.dir" do jboss 5.1?

Comment: acho que vc deveria mockar, até pq essa é um configuração de ambiente, que acha?

Comment: Sou iniciante em testes, não pude estudar como fazer mocking ainda. Pode me dar um exemplo superficial de como ficaria um mock neste caso?

Comment: Veja: https://blog.caelum.com.br/facilitando-seus-testes-de-unidade-no-java-um-pouco-de-mockito/, depois https://stackoverflow.com/a/35393623/2615692